# Actions before logout from ssh session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, unix, shell

Is it possible to bind some actions which will be executed before logout from `ssh` session?

I mean some config like `.bashrc`, etc.

Comment: What do you want executed? A script or are you running commands that run for awhile so you want to exit and keep them running?

Comment: I want execute just a single command. But answer not a best place for comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you enter the following into `.bashrc` (or `/etc/profile`, or `.profile`, or any other start-up script) on the remote machine:

```
function onexit { xmessage "Exiting..."; }; trap onexit EXIT
```

You can replace the `xmessage` command with anything you want: if you use `/etc/profile` you will need to make checks that `bash` is in a remote session, so as not to affect local sessions.

[The answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129923/bash-run-command-before-a-script-exits) deal with exiting scripts, but are equally valid for the shell itself.

Comment: Works like a charm!